# boost regex_match vs regex_search

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Does regex_search becomes equivalent to regex_match while matching something in a string if my regex pattern has the following form: `^.......$`, i.e. if I tell that what is matched should be in start of the string and should end with the end of the string? Or is there any other difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they aren't equivalent, because the $ in regex_search will match the line-end and ^ will match line-start.
So in a multi-line string the regex_search would still find sub-matches.
I guess adding the flags boost::match_not_eol and boost::match_not_bol would create the regex_match behaviour.

Comment: There may also be a difference in performance. `regex_search` will probably try matching at every position in the string, even if the pattern can only succeed at the beginning. `regex_match` knows better.